# How to solve this trigonometry problem with complex numbers?

Tags: complex-numbers

If
$$a = \cos(q) + i \sin(q)$$
$$b = \cos(r) + i\sin(r)$$
$$c = \cos(e) + i\sin(e)$$
$$b/c + c/a + a/b = 1$$

then what is the value of

$$\cos(r-e) \cos(e-q) +\cos(q-r)$$?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$\dfrac bc=\cdots=\cos(r-e)+i\sin(r-e)$

Now equate the real parts.

Comment: See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula